# How can I switch to the user jenkins in the middle of a ssh script?

Tags: ssh, sudo, sh, su

I run

```
ssh root@myhost "sh -x" < myremotecommands.sh
```

where myremotecommands.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo su
apt-get update
sudo su -l -p jenkins
whoami
```

however the command whoami returns 'root'.
I need to be user jenkins to perform some installations.

How can I switch to the user jenkins in the middle of the script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$USER`. That will give you the username you logged in as. `Whoami` returns the user you're currently operating as.

Comment: Use $USER. Why?

Answer (score 10):

You just have to use "su" command with "-s /bin/bash" argument. It´s needed because jenkins user was not supposed to be used interactively, so it doesn´t have the bash defined.

```
su jenkins -s /bin/bash
```

After this, the "whoami" command will report you as "jenkins"  user.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo su
apt-get update
su jenkins <<HERE
whoami
echo usr=$USER
HERE
```

will output:
jenkins
usr=root

Source:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/shell-scripting/threads/14498